# How I can apply static memory allocation rather than dynamic allocation?

Tags: memory, static, tokenize

How I can change the function from dynamic allocation to static allocation for the tokinize function which is use the same logic of strtok. It is working fine using the dynamic allocation but could not figure out how i can modify it to work with static allocation

```
char **tokenize ( char *string, char delimiter) {
char **lines = NULL;
char **temp = NULL;
char limit[2] = "";
size_t skip = 0;
size_t span = 0;
size_t extent = 0;
size_t line = 0;
size_t len = strlen ( string);

limit[0] = delimiter;

if ( NULL == ( lines = malloc ( sizeof ( *lines) * 2))) {//allocate two pointers
    fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
    return NULL;
}
lines[line + 1] = NULL;//sentinel

while ( extent < len) {
    skip = strspn ( string + extent, limit);//get number of delimiters
    extent += skip;//advance past spaces
    if ( ( span = strcspn ( string + extent, limit))) {//find next delimiter or '\0'
        if ( NULL == ( lines[line] = malloc ( span + 1))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "malloc problem\n");
            return lines;
        }
        strncpy ( lines[line], string + extent, span);
        lines[line][span] = '\0';

        if ( NULL == ( temp = realloc ( lines, sizeof ( *lines) * ( line + 3)))) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "realloc problem\n");
            return lines;
        }
        lines = temp;
        line++;
        lines[line] = NULL;
        lines[line + 1] = NULL;//sentinel
        extent += span;//advance past the token
    }
}//loop to end of string

return lines;
```

}

Comment: Generally switching to static allocation (from heap allocation) is a bad idea. Why do you want to make such a switch? Read about [static variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_variable)s

Comment: As I read prevent  using dynamic allocation  in embedded system and better to use static allocation   @Basile Starynkevitch

Comment: So use static data everywhere, or code your own `malloc` implementation. If you can't use `malloc` you should not use most other C standard functions (even `fopen` or `strtok`) which can call it.